# Sass error on Travis CI only

Tags: ruby-on-rails, sass, travis-ci

My app passes all my RSpec tests on my local machine. But when I build it on Travis CI I get the following eror:

```
/home/travis/build/joegattnet/joegattnet_v3/lib/sass.rb:8:in `<module:Functions>': 
undefined method `declare' for Sass::Script::Functions:Module (NoMethodError)
from /home/travis/build/joegattnet/joegattnet_v3/lib/sass.rb:3:in `<top (required)>
```

[etc]

Why would this work on my machine but not on Travis CI? I have a dedicated gemset on my machine and my .travis.yml file specifies the exact Ruby version.

FWIW, the contents of the file in question are:

```
# encoding: utf-8

module Sass::Script::Functions
  def settings_styling(setting)
    assert_type setting, :String
    Sass::Script::Parser.parse(Settings.styling[setting.value].to_s, 0, 0)
  end
  declare :settings_styling, args: [:setting]
end
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved this by putting the file into /config/initializers/sass.rb. I'm not sure this is where it should go, though.